# implement scrollView in form

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I am trying to add `ScrollView` in my form. But whenever I add `ScrollView` it is showing **"`ScrollView` can host only one direct child"**.What does that mean?And How can I implement `ScrollView` in my form? Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/showImage"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    <!--android:src="@drawable/placeholder"-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#f66565"
        android:text="Select Image" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editFirstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Blog Title">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editLastName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Blog Description" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editWeb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Web Link">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNewUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#f66565"
            android:text="New Blog" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSaveRecord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#f66565"
            android:text="Save Blog" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnfullinfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#f66565"
            android:text="Show All" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you must have only child in your `ScrollView` means `<ScrollView>--<LinearLayout>--All Other layouts--</LinearLayout></ScrollView>`

Comment: `ScrollView` can have only one element inside it. Enclose the other elements in a linear layout.

Comment: You guys don't have google??

Comment: thank you Abhishek Patel :)

Comment: @SamiurRahman always wc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scroll view can contain only one child view. so you should use the top view as scroll view and make a child view as linear or relative or other as you want. then add all other views like button or text view in that linear or relative layout. you can't add more child view in a scroll view. here your code should be like:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/showImage"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        <!--android:src="@drawable/placeholder"-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSaveImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#f66565"
            android:text="Select Image" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editFirstName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Blog Title">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editLastName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Blog Description" />

       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editWeb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Web Link">

            <requestFocus />
       </EditText>

       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNewUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="#f66565"
                android:text="New Blog" />

           <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSaveRecord"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="#f66565"
                android:text="Save Blog" />

           <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnfullinfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="#f66565"
                android:text="Show All" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: don't use more than one layout into a scrollView

Answer (score 2):

A `ScrollView` can host only one direct child, that means you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll.

This child may itself be a layout manager with a hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a `LinearLayout` in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

Try Like This

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

       // all other views currently in your ScrollView
 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanx i know it will work like a charm i understand now...  :)